# Uploading image in background ios

Tags: ios7, ios8

I know there is NSURLSession class which is launched in iOS7 and it does have NSURLSessionUploadTask for uploading data to server, But I need to know whether it will continue uploading even after in background mode if no? then what to do for continue that task in background mode too for complete uploading.

previously we can use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and endBackgroundTask: which will continue that task to max 10 minutes for iOS6 but in iOS 7 and above it will hardly run upto 3 minutes (as per my knowledge).

So can you please help me guys for any solution or example if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your first question is probably YES, you can continue uploading for the tim e that is permitted by the iOS but for that you need use **UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier** to get hold of that extra time.

And for the second part of your question for uploading the remaining images when the app is not running you can use Background fetch. When you enable Background fetch the app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network. So probably by combining **UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier** and **Background fetch** you can achieve uploading the images in background.

Below mentioned are the steps to combine UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier and Background fetch.

First let's initialise **UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier**

```
-(void) beginBackgroundUploadTask
{
    if(self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        [self endBackgroundUploadTask];
    }

    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        [self endBackgroundUploadTask];

    }];
}
```

Once the background task runs out of time from the stipulated allotted time, we should invalidate and end the background task.

```
-(void) endBackgroundUploadTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask ];
    self. backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Do not forget to enable Background Modes in Xcode → Select Project File → Capabilities → Check the Background fetch checkbox.

For further info you can refer the link below: 
http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/background-fetch-ios/

Comment: I'll try to do this...but one small question is there that how frequently performFetchWithCompletionHandler will be called and for how much time, OR its depend on iOS? thanks appreciating you.

Comment: When Background Fetch is trigged performFetchWithCompletionHandler method is called and its trigged by iOS depending upon the usage of the app. As far as the amount of time is considered as per my debugging and knowledge during implementing this the background fetch, you have around 10 secs which you can increase upto 30 to 180 secs (depending upon the system resources) using the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier. Hope this answers your question.